# now(); and date(); function in code igniter give zeros result

Tags: php, codeigniter

So i want to insert current time to mysql database, this is my code :

```
'regis_date'=>$this->input->post(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', now()))
```

But the result is this : `0000-00-00 00:00:00`
What i want is like this (for example) : `2012-08-31 00:00:00`
Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`$this->input->post`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html) is for retrieving data posted through a form.

E.g.:

```
<input type="text" name="regis_date" />
```

Can be retrieved like this:

```
$this->input->post('regis_date');
```

Passing a date to `$this->input->post` doesn't make any sense. What you want is:

```
'regis_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', now())
```

Or as zerkms rightfully remarks:

```
'regis_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
'regis_date'=>'NOW()'
```

**Edited**
Use this one . . It works for sure . .

```
'regis_date'=>date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
```

Comment: Just give date('Y-m-d H:i:s') or just "now()"